# Angular 2: NgForm with multiple buttons

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I am trying to develop a cart. The whole cart comprises of multiple buttons such as add/remove/proceed etc. I want the validation to be applied only on proceed button which has a type submit. But currently on click of any of the buttons the validations are activated.

I cannot post the code as it is quite a complex one. Just let me know if this is the normal behavior with the forms or I might be having some errors on my part.

Thanks

Comment: just make process button as submit button and make other buttons as type="button" on their click event do some task.

Comment: I have done the same but before calling the function program calls for vaildations

Comment: can u plz provide your code in which you are getting error? update your question with your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form #groupForm="ngForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="submit(groupForm.value)"> 
  <input type="text" name="user" ngModel required>

  <button (click)="accessGroup(group)" [disabled]="groupForm.invalid" type="submit">Proceed</button>

  <button>Add</button>
  <button>Remove</button>
</form>
```